# How can I return all unique entries that satisfy criteria from other tables?

Tags: mysql, select

I'll fabricate data to illustrate my question:
I have 2 tables, one called `clients`, and one called `shippingProfiles`.

```
                   clients                           shippingProfiles
    *************************************   *********************************
    * clientId username   emailAddress  *   * clientId  street     town     *
    * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *   * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
    * 1        james      jdoer@aol.org *   * 1         mole       north    *
    * 2        zac        zmit@aol.org  *   * 1         maple      pleasant *
    * 3        cris       cm@yahoo.org  *   * 3         oak        brook    *
    * 4        john       jg@yahoo.org  *   * 3         taylor     glen     *
    *************************************   *********************************
```

`clients.clientId` is a unique primary key. Some of the clients have multiple shipping profiles, others have none.

I would like to search the database for any client that has the letter "m" in their username, emailAddress, street, or town. I would like each unique client to be returned as one entry (and only one entry), showing their id, username, email address, street, and town. If they don't have a street and town it can display `null` (or something similar), and if they have multiple streets and towns it can display any one of them.

This should be the result:

```
    *********************************************************
    * clientId  username  emailAddress    street  town      *
    * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
    * 1         james     jdoer@aol.org   mole    north     *
    * 2         zac       zmit@aol.org    null    null      *
    * 3         cris      cm@yahoo.org    oak     brook     *
    *********************************************************
```

The tables may eventually hold 50,000 entries each so I need the database to do this in the least possible sweeps.

I've heard mysql is actually very powerful so I'm assuming this can be done with one command.

Comment: this problem uses `LIKE`, eg `username LIKE '%m%'` which kills the index. If you have huge database, the query will execute very slow because it performs `full table scan`. I'll recommend you to read about `FULL TEXT SEARCH`.

Comment: 50,000 entries is small potatoes for any relational database  The problme with your above is your doing an inner join which means records are being excluded if one table doesn't contain data.  Change your join to `FROM Clients LEFT JOIN shippingProfiles on Clients.ClientID = ShippingProfiles.clientID` then what you have should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a left outer join - this will attempt to join the row to all other rows, but if it didn't do any join it still prints all the fields, just putting null in the ones that were from the other table.

select * from clients LEFT OUTER JOIN shippingProfiles ON clients.clientId = shippingProfiles.ID

WHERE clients.username LIKE '%m%' OR --insert other conditions here